# Simulate Logistic Regression with fixed number of Y=1 or successes

Tags: r

I am trying to simulate data for a logistic regression.  Say I have the following setup, shamelessly lifted from Ocram's example here (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12857/generate-random-correlated-data-between-a-binary-and-a-continuous-variable/12858#12858):

```
n <- 20
b0 <- -1.6
b1 <- 0.03
b2 <- 0.5
x1 <- runif(n=n, min=18, max=60)
x2 <- rnorm(n=n, 0, 2)
pi_x <- exp(b0 + b1 * x1 + b2 * x2) / (1 + exp(b0 + b1 * x1 + b2 * x2))
y <- rbinom(n=length(x1), size=1, prob=pi_x)
data <- data.frame(x1, x2, pi_x, y)
print(data)
```

My goal is to simulate this data with a fixed or specific number of successes in the outcome variable y, by adjusting the value of b0 as needed.  My rough idea (inside a loop or apply call) was to simulate the data with b0 drawn randomly from a uniform distribution, check the number of successes and increase or decrease b0 as necessary, then re-check iteratively until I settle on a value of b0 that works.

This is incredibly inelegant, though, and I hope there is a more sensible way.

Comment: uniform distribution in which range? shall it be an integer or double? check the number of successes and increase or decrease based on which condition? how do you settle on a value? which are the conditions?

Comment: Sorry LyzandeR, my post wasn't clear.  I'm not sure about the range of the uniform distribution.  A brief example: Say my goal is to have precisely 10 successes out of 20.  I would check the number of 1's in y.  If it is 9, then take b0, add 1, re-simulate.  Then re-check the number of 1's in y, if it is still 9, add 1 to b0, then re-simulate.  Once there are precisely 10 1's in y, the inside loop stops and the simulation moves on to the next task, not discussed here.  I know that is messy, though.

Comment: You could wrap the last few lines into a function, with the return values being the proportion of 0 or 1. Throw that into an `sapply` over a sensible range of `b0`values and see where the ratio is where you want it. Once you have the approximate value for `b0`, repeat the simulation process until you get exactly the right ratio.

Comment: @LyzandeR where did your answer go?  I hadn't had a chance to look at it in detail yet.

Comment: Yeah it wasn't good enough I suppose. I just realized what you need. You needed it to go through a logistic regression essentially. So, I gave it some thought and tbh since you use the `rbinom` function it will be very difficult to be able to get an equal number of Ys or Ns.

Comment: Let me think about it some more. If you can give me any more details feel free.

Comment: Btw unless I get something wrong you need Ys and Ns as output. I don't know how `rbinom` will help in this occasion as it produces the number of successes in a trial of `size` observations i.e. it will produce a number between [0,size] according to the probability.

Comment: I think that essentially what you need is whether pi_x is greater or less than 0.5 so that you can identify each Bernoulli observation as Y or N. I think `rbinom` is redundant. Am I correct? If we agree on that I ll tell you what I think. (Feel free to disagree :) I like such conversations and I might be forgetting sth important)